# How to read data from an application which is running

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to develop an application which reads a data from another application.

In the image i want to read the columns which are presented their and save it in a text file or database.

[image]

Can anyone please help me in this regard!

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I dont understand the question.

Comment: Does that application do exposes any API to talk to or perhaps stores the information in DB or files so that you can read? 
I do not think you can talk to other non managed applicaiton so easily.

Comment: You want to communicate with another application? Check if that application has an API. This is the way to go unless they let you export or you really have A LOT of time and patience to analyze what is shown on the screen

Comment: their are certain columns in which the data is updated for every second. I need that data for my application to develop.so i want to read the listview contained in that application and save it in a text file or database.Note : It updates every second

Comment: Check if that application has an API ? how to know it because i dont have any idea about it

Comment: check the vendors website and its developers page if there is or contact them

Comment: I contacted them and they told that the application has an API.now what i should do.

Comment: Use the API.  Seriously.  Ask the vendor if they have documentation and/or samples for how to use their API - they most likely do.  Play around with the samples and if you're still stuck come back and ask questions.  Just make sure you give enough information in your question for people to give you an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Look into using the Microsoft accessibility layer. MSAA (older) and UIA (newer) are two accessibility APIs provided by Windows for accessibility tools (screen readers, etc) to get at and modify the UI on screen. This makes them very useful for other things, like testing, screen scraping, etc. They are well-documented on MSDN, for hwnd UIs everything starts with WM_GETOBJECT.

Comment: can u please provide me a link or a sample . Because I am new to what you are saying.

Comment: MSDN entry for UIA is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx.  There is a decent blog describing how to use UIA at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winuiautomation/archive/2012/03/06/windows-7-ui-automation-client-api-c-sample-e-mail-reader-version-1-0.aspx.